# Nginx not working when redirecting react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nginx

I have been following DigitalOceans tutorial on using nginx to redirect ip addresses from example:3000 to just example or example/eg, this works fine for my root location / directory but when trying to put a separate react application in location /weather it doesn't work - it just shows a blank page with the title of React App. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Seb

Comment: Hi Seb, the minimum that you need to add here for someone to answer this question is you NGINX config and your folder structure. Else, you're just going to get downvoted. Cheers!

Comment: It sounds as it the public index.html is loaded, but react not started. If you created the app with create-react-app it might be you did not set your subfolder correctly in the config, and as a result react javascript cannot be loaded.
However without more information this is just a wild guess based on your symptoms.

Comment: @RogierSlag Thanks for your response, the website is working fine when I go to domain:4002. but not when I go domain/weather.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can set your environment flag `PUBLIC_URL` in that case to include the subfolder in the build